# Apache POI Parsing error

Tags: java, apache-poi

I know this question has been asked often, but couldn't find a suitable solution.
When working with

```
XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(srcFile);
```

or

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(srcFile);
```

I always end up with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V from class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:313)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:163)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:131)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:561)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:109)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:80)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.<init>(PackagePart.java:125)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.<init>(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:243)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:266)
```

People have suggested to open `PackageRelationshipCollection` and retry. But that didn't help much.

Also I have the jars loaded :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.13</version>
   <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C):

> **Can I mix POI jars from different versions?**
>
> No. This is not supported.
>
> All POI jars in use must come from the same version. A combination such as poi-3.11.jar and poi-ooxml-3.9.jar is not supported, and will fail to work in unpredictable ways.

Your pom has dependencies on Apache POI jars from  3.11, 3.12 and 3.13, which as [the FAQ explained isn't supported](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C)

You need to change all of those to be 3.13, then it'll work

I'd suggest something like:

```
<properties>
  <poi.version>3.13</poi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- etc as needed -->
```

That way, you can ensure all your POI jars are from the same version!